# Shadows in unity 3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, shadow

I am working in unity 3d. I have to make shadow for a character controller. I tried to make  it and changed to hard shadows. But shadows are not visible. Have directional light in scene, intensity is 0.5 How to make them visible ?

Comment: Do you own Unity Pro?  Unity free means no shadows.

Comment: yes. i have Unity Pro. Tried all suggestions written below. Still not getting shadows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only a single directional light will cast shadows, so ensure to not have 2+.
Also ensure to have it set as important.

Then they should appear if you are close enough to see them, you define that in the quality settings, they are not "long range" (for long range there is lightmapping)
close, given you went by the unity defined default human size (from the character package - so about 2-3 3d units high), means 20 or so human heights away

Oh and ensure you aren't on a mobile targeted project cause on mobile there are no shadows
taken from [here](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/89037-No-shadows)

Although the [shadow requirements](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/Shadows.html) says that shadows are possible in some mobile devices, but I've never got any shadow in my unity projects when the target is mobile.

Comment: i did your suggestion. but no shadows

Comment: Are you trying any mobile platform? And have you changed the quality settings too to allow hard or soft shadows?

Comment: yes i changed to hard shadows. i am trying in mobile platform also

Comment: For mobile platform you need to have a non-tegra based processor and OpenGL ES 2.0 supported device. Although sometimes it doesn't show up in other phones too. Ensure the ES 2.0 setting is selected.

Answer (score 2):

You mean you tried to make a shadow for a model, which you have applied a character controller to? - A character controller standalone isn't meant to be visible or drop shadows

Have you added any kind of light to your scene, this is mandatory, so that shadows can be droped

Comment: ya i added directional light

Comment: You  can also check the render mode of directional light , it should be important so that can solve your problem